# Temporarily show a message in the modeline?

Tags: mode-line

How can I print a message for a period of time to the mode line and restore the default format afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporarily change [`mode-line-format`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Top.html) or any of [its constituent variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html).

See the Elisp manual, node [Mode Line Format](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html) and its subnodes.

For example (taken from [`icicle-show-in-mode-line`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-mode.el)):

```el
(defun my-show-in-mode-line (text &optional buffer delay)
  "Display TEXT in BUFFER's mode line.
The text is shown for DELAY seconds (default 2), or until a user event.
So call this last in a sequence of user-visible actions."
  (message nil) ; Remove any current msg
  (with-current-buffer (or buffer  (current-buffer))
    (make-local-variable 'mode-line-format) ; Needed for Emacs 21+.
    (let ((mode-line-format  text))
      (force-mode-line-update) (sit-for (or delay  2)))
    (force-mode-line-update)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can save the current value of `mode-line-format` [(elisp manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html#Mode-Line-Format) before changing it, then use a timer [(manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html#Timers) to set it back to the saved value.

```el
(defun temporary-mode-line (text time)
  "Display TEXT in mode line for TIME seconds."
  (let ((old mode-line-format)
    (buf (current-buffer)))
    (setq mode-line-format text)
    (run-at-time time nil
            (lambda (v b)
              (with-current-buffer b
                (setq mode-line-format v)
                (force-mode-line-update)))
            old buf)))
```

Comment: I accepted the answer from Drew because he was first although yours is a good answer as well, thanks.