# How to show a message in the echo area not immediately but after a certain delay and to disappear it after a certain delay

Tags: echo-area, message

The following show the message "something" in the echo area immediately, and this message remains there unless I do a second action (e.g. moving the cursor, executing anther command etc)

```
(message "something")
```

I would like that the message to not appear immediately, but after a delay of few second (say 2 seconds) and to automatically disappear after few second (say 3 second). Is this possible?

To be precise I would like that in the first delay of 2 seconds, I would able to see other system messages (if any).

Comment: The display of a message for a finite period of time is already treated there: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18479/temporarily-show-a-message-in-the-modeline/18481#18481. If you display something temporarily you should restore the old message afterwards. Therefore, save what you get via `(current-message)` and view it afterwards via `(message ...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That question was about modeline.Here is about the echo area. They are related though not identical.

Comment: Oh, yes right you are. Sorry, for the confusion. When I read the other question I thought about the difference of `minibuffer` and `echo area` and got into that trap. Nevertheless, the other part of the comment about `(current-message)` is worth to think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
(run-with-timer 2 nil
        (lambda ()
          (message "Some message")
          (run-with-timer 3 nil
                  (lambda ()
                    (message nil)))))
```

`run-with-timer` will call a function of your choice after a delay (there's a `run-with-idle-timer` variant if you want to only show the message when Emacs is idle). I've used `lambda` here to create an anonymous function with the body of code I want to run.

The example shows a message then schedules a second timer to clear the echo-area.

This is a bit clumsy since there might be somebody else's message in the echo area by the time the second timer fires, so you may end up clearing a different message. There's probably a way to avoid that with some more work.

*Edit: changed (message "") to (message nil) to clear the echo-area and return to showing any minibuffer contents (thanks Drew!)*

Comment: Use `(message nil)`, to clear the message and let the contents of the minibuffer show.

Comment: The documentation of this function (25.1) suggests that these invocations are equivalent.

Comment: I confirm that this solution works. Let me wait for possible alternative solution.

Comment: How can we make this the default behavior for all kinds of echoed text including messages? I mean, let them disappear after a delay.

Comment: Seems the variable minibuffer-message-timeout should work out of the box, but it doesn't.
I have come up with this:
 (fset 'original-message (symbol-function 'message))
(defun clear-message (&rest args)
    (run-with-timer 2 nil
        (lambda () (original-message nil))))

you can test it with

(run-with-timer 2 nil
        (lambda ()
          (message "Some message")))

Maybe it's better to set inhibit-message at entry and exit of the minibuffer